# Connecting RFID reader over USB

Tags: usb, serial, rfid

I just purchased the RFIDRW-E-USB RFID reader from Priority 1 Design (see [this page](http://www.priority1design.com.au/rfid_reader_modules.html#animal_tag_reader_writer), datasheet available in PDF form.)

I have tried to make it work on my computer (Ubuntu), before plugging it to my Raspberry Pi, but I had not luck so far and I am running out of ideas on how to make it work.

I connected the provided antenna to the A+ and A- nodes on the board but did not solder it in place, as I plan on installing another antenna later and I'm not really good at welding. (I made sure the stripped part of the wire was touching a metal part on the board, and taped them in place.)

Then, I plugged the whole thing in my computer, and I can see the board as `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Then, inspired by the code for a Parallax RFID reader (from [here](http://www.sundh.com/blog/2013/09/connect-parallax-rfid-to-raspberry-pi/)), I tried the following in Python (with super user privilege):

```
import serial

device = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 2400, timeout=5)
while True:
    tag = device.read(12)  # Tries to read the ISO tag format made of 12 digits
    if len(tag) != 0:  # If something has been read, print it then break out of the loop
        print tag
        break
```

When I approach a tag, nothing happens.

Is there a flaw in my method? What is the most likely cause of error in these steps?

**EDIT:** After contacting their customer support, I have been told to use a virtual com port driver to communicate with the FTDI chip, from [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm). Since I want to code in python, I will try various python modules for FTDI chips.

**EDIT2:** So now I can communicate with my device, but only in interactive mode. I can use `screen` to connect: `sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0`. Then, I can use the various commands shown in the datasheet. If I enter `ver` (followed by a carriage return), I receive the expected output `?09`. Now I just need to do the same in Python...

**EDIT3:** The FTDI chip is FT232RL. Google shows me a lot of people successfully using this chip with Python (in bitbang mode). There must be something simple I'm missing...

Comment: what is your script for the virtual com port driver? I'm trying to use the same rfid reader, but i'm stock and looking for all the possibilities.

Comment: It has been a while since I worked with it, but from what I remember, I did not use any other script or driver. It was all in the default `serial` module of python.

Answer (score 2):

One of the good points about Python is that you can use it interactively.

From a command prompt type python.

Then try out the commands.

```
import serial
import time

device = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 2400)

while True:

   print(device.read(12)) # important to indent this line
   time.sleep(1)  # important to indent this line

# press return here to execute the while loop
# control C to abort while loop

device.write("ver")
device.read(12)
```

Anything you can get working interactively will work in a script.

Comment: That is the weird thing: When I have `/dev/ttyUSB0` open in screen, then I do `device.write("ver")` (in another terminal), I see the reply in screen. But, when I try `device.read(12)` in python, I get nothing (an empty string).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the serial module you are using.  Rather than read(12) which may block until 12 bytes are available I'd call a function which spins testing for data availability (inWaiting) then reads/prints that number of characters.

Comment: Your python program may not be opening the device with the right settings to run by itself.